# netplan gre tunnel

Tags: 20.04, netplan

I want to add gre tunnel in netplan.

name: gre0, mode: gre, remote: 10.11.22.100, local: 10.11.22.99, dev: eth1
I don't know what key value to put interface eth1 into gre0.

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            addresses: []
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.8.9
        eth1:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            addresses: []
        eth2:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            mtu: 1500
            addresses:
            - 10.11.29.11/16
            - fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:fd2d/64
            routes:
            -
                to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 10.11.0.1
                metric: 1
    tunnels:
        gre0:
            mode: gre
            local: 10.11.22.99
            remote: 10.11.22.100
            addresses:
            - 10.11.22.90/24
            mtu: 1500
```

The result of netplan apply was also different from what I expected.
I don't know why gretap0 and erspan0 are created.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:83:fd:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:fd37/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:83:fd:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:fd41/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:83:fd:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.11.29.11/16 brd 10.11.255.255 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:fd2d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: gre0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    inet 10.11.22.90/24 brd 10.11.22.255 scope global gre0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: erspan0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1450 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not put an ethernet device "into" a tunnel.  A tunnel runs on top of your existing network layer.  The `local` address of a tunnel specifies which of your local IP addresses to use for the tunnel endpoint, and the `remote` address of a tunnel specifies the already-reachable (via Internet or intranet) address of the other end of the tunnel.

In your config above, you have specified as `local` an IP address (10.11.22.99) that does not appear to actually be local (i.e., this is not a configured address on any of your interfaces).  It is not clear that the `remote` you have specified is correct either, since it falls within the network you're defining (via `addresses`) as being routed *across* the tunnel.

`addresses` are the addresses assigned to the tunnel.  `remote` and `local` are the addresses of the two tunnel endpoints which are outside the tunnel and used to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `gre0` name is restricted to [GRE](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/ip_tunnel.c#L72) fallback (say when `IP.src` and `IP.dst` for the specific tunnel do not match, `10.11.22.100 -> 10.11.22.99` in your case). Reason why you have the defaults `gre0@NONE` etc. created by `ip_gre` kernel module.

You should change the name to `mygre` for example ;)